Connect LED tapes using FFC or other flexible cable to go around obstacle
Two led tapes of width ~1cm sit 1cm apart. Between them in the middle, there's an obstacle around 3mm thick. I want to connect the LED tapes with a flexible cable that goes around the obstacle. FFCs come to mind, but I'm not sure what's best. Do you have any ideas for alternative approaches? I discovered JST FFC Connectors in the Similar Questions section before making this post. Would a JST FFC approach be relatively feasible in a DIY project? Ideally, the cable should snap in and be easy to disconnect, in order to make the tape pieces modular and easy to replace. My LED tape is a bit dense (144 LEDs per meter) and has 3 pins as shown in the image. I may have to do something about the limited length on the edges, but my main concern is picking the right cable/connector approach.
(And apologies for the low-res picture & bad soldering)

As you can see, using regular wire takes up too much space.



please add a picture that shows the problem area

what is wrong with using wire?

How much current must pass the wiring over the 1cm gap? BTW, this is too large scale for being classified as microelectronics, and usually electrical things are soldered, not welded.

I edited the post. Using wire takes up too much space and the solder metal isn't shock-proof, although this probably also has to do with the solder itself. It sticks fine to the surface but if I bend the wires, some of the force causes them to come off. As for the current, maybe this datasheet helps: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2757/p2757_SK6812RGBW_REV01.pdf
The aliexpress listing no longer exists but the title had "SK6812 RGBW" and "Similar WS2812B" so, it should be the SK6812 RGBW.

run separate power wires in parallel with the LED strips ... attach thinner drop connections to each LED strip section ... the data connections can use thin wire
